# How to do tensorflow inference with multiple models?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, inference

Suppose I have 2 `tf.keras` models that work with images, and I want to use these models inside my C++ standalone program which reads images from 2 cameras continuously and run the model on each frame. Each camera has a different frame rate, so both models must be run in parallel, they need to utilize GPU also.
Each model predicts different things.

The C++ app is only on one desktop PC, it does not need to serve the predictions to many people, so tensorflow serving might be overkill or not fast? I am suspecting it is not fast because I saw that it's using JSON to encode predictions, which might be slow to send or receive.

I have saved both models as `SavedModel` format and it can be predicted fine in python.

How can I load these 2 models and predict in parallel utilizing one GPU, and as fast as possible in C++ app? I only care about the case when the prediction is a single image, or 2 images, not a batch like 32 images. If there is a way to make tensorflow serving or lite works fast, I am also cool with that.

Bonus: the method should not require difficult installation that users have to do. Think that in the end user will have to install my app and they have to manually install tensorflow dependencies? That's impractical.